# HRESULT 0x80072F7D on a https request with client certificate over Windows.Web.HttpClient from Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, client-certificates

I am trying to access a json from a server over Windows.Web.HttpClient from a Windows Phone 8.1 App.

But for security reasons there is a proxy server with client authentication certificates. I am able to set the Client Authentication Certificate but it always fails with an error. The error-message is "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F7D"

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Framework.Mobile.Widgets.LoginPage.<Btn_Login_Click>d__0.MoveNext()
```

The SSL-Certificate on the server is an wildcard certificate for my entire domain, the client certificate is a self-signed certificate.

Access the Service over the Internet Explorer on Windows Phone works fine, so i think it is a error of the HttpClient. Any Ideas?

mfg harmoniemand

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for your fast reply.it is a windows phone, so I am not able to capture WinHTTP-Logs.

Comment: Hmya, that server is not a phone.  Or run your app from the emulator.  Or try it first in a Store app.  No lack for options here.  Also get the server admin involved to help you solve this problem.

Comment: How are you setting the client certificate?

Comment: i am setting them by sending it by mail to the device an install it by a simple click.

Comment: did you fix your issue?

Comment: no i dont. it is still broken.